# Why are packages/modules in the python standard library monolithic

Tags: python

I sometimes look at the [Python source](https://hg.python.org/cpython) to see how some features were implemented. With the "recent" inclusion of [Pathlib](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a14f6a70d013/Lib/pathlib.py) in the standard library, I read through the code to understand how they did it. The first thing I noticed is that Pathlib, like many other stdlib modules, is a single file -- in this case just under 1500 lines.

I am wondering if there is a reason why so much of the Python stdlib consists of these long monolithic modules -- as opposed to packages like, say, [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests).

I can think of the following reasons:

- Performance -- am I even right in assuming that single-file modules are faster in Python?
- Re-usability is not a concern if it's already in the standard library.
- Flat is better than nested?

Is there any other reason?

Comment: I don't know if there be much, if any, performance difference. And being in the standard library makes it *more* important that the code is well-structured; lots of people are using it! Quite a few are modules, e.g. [`json`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a14f6a70d013/Lib/json).

Comment: 1500 is not particularly huge.  I'd say it's more about the complexity of the API than the number of lines in the module.

Answer (score 0):

At least from an embedded system point of view, having monolithic files means less I/O.  In the case of these small systems that may use SD cards for I/O, being able to open a single file is much better than opening 20 small files.

This at least is one reason a monolithic design could be chosen.